# Do blue items respawn?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've noticed that blue shining item pickups are all over the world, but some are better than others, e.g. Potion versus, say, a Phoenix Down. If I wait a while and go back, will these items respawn or are they one-time pickups only? Since Oracle Ascension Coins are blue shiny pickups and are one-time collectible items, this leads me to believe that blue shiny pickups do *not* respawn.

Comment: I know the red treasure ones do, as I farmed the Whiskers for cash early on.

Comment: I believe the blue ones also respawn, but they are random from a list available to the region your in. Id have to test it or do more research to be sure.

Comment: I believe some of them respawn as I'm fairly confident I have got the same blue item multiple times from the same spot.

Comment: Some respawn and some don't. There used to be a Save & Reload explore people used to farm items but recent questions about blue item respawn are answered with "they don't" after the last patch update date while videos and explanation of methods of how to do it are from before the patch. So, I figure it was a silent fix. I have experienced some blue items respawning when I first got the game but haven't noticed it lately.

Comment: They definitely respawn. I was doing hunts last night and one of them took me in front of a dungeon that I had previously finished, and I distinctly remember picking up three of the blue items along the pathway...they were there again when I went to the area to do the hunt.